# Accessing to the Facebook profile picture

Tags: json, angularjs, facebook

I am using Firebase in order to do a Facebook auth, I would like to know how to display and access to the profile picture from the returned json which looks like this

```
{
  "uid": "facebook:1419891304993631",
  "provider": "facebook",
  "facebook": {
    "id": "1419891304993631",
    "accessToken": "CAAJdUVn89vwBAKYZASyfcpTEeSNZApxJEy7xDoCe8M02xZBCJeW6bneWbPJiXYXo0Oe3BVt4hL4xmVkQG5DnQPUs4AeXf67vx2p5kXPvk0vgsB7EPWUhDQzDZAXa1JLdCZBaVhNDtv39dqyH24qwqVzTxKqH8DRPeSPqga5DjZBsAaqmhcaMyPNXZB26NPZA8RZCS8J0zZAmyO67Lq7W5y3der",
    "displayName": "Aaron Hillel Swartz",
    "email": "retana.marcelo@gmail.com",
    "cachedUserProfile": {
      "id": "1419891304993631",
      "name": "Aaron Hillel Swartz",
      "last_name": "Swartz",
      "first_name": "Aaron",
      "middle_name": "Hillel",
      "gender": "male",
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/1419891304993631/",
      "email": "retana.marcelo@gmail.com",
      "picture": {
        "data": {
          "is_silhouette": false,
          "url": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xfp1/v/t1.0-1/s100x100/111…77b0ef39e0&oe=55A9B547&__gda__=1436644689_2ba73b2df6e584b46e5a2f8000d571d8"
        }
      },
      "age_range": {
        "min": 21
      },
      "locale": "es_LA",
      "timezone": -6
    }
  },
  "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ2IjowLCJkIjp7InVpZCI6ImZhY2Vib29rOjE0MTk4OTEzMDQ5OTM2MzEiLCJwcm92aWRlciI6ImZhY2Vib29rIn0sImlhdCI6MTQyOTA4NTA4OH0.ec-5bS1-sTSUfeBwDZRwncZxuABrHwnlIQY5eLYxQBQ",
  "auth": {
    "uid": "facebook:1419891304993631",
    "provider": "facebook"
  },
  "expires": 1429171488
}
```

example, with this

```
<div ng-bind="user.uid"></div>
```

I can display de user uid which is `facebook:1419891304993631` in this case, so, with angular, how can I access to the profile picture property ?

Is there a way to use like a kind of `ng-src` for this?

Comment: <img src="user.facebook.cachedUserProfile.picture.data.url">

Comment: @ramamoorthy_villi error: ```GET http://localhost:8100/user.facebook.cachedUserProfile.picture.data.url 404 (Not Found)```

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer Can you use angular notation(json) in a normal src tag?(the answer is no)

Comment: @Daedalus so what should I do ?

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer Is there a particular reason you can't use what you mentioned as your last sentence in this question?

Comment: @Daedalus I did not get you, sorry. I just did ```<img ng-src="user.facebook.cachedUserProfile.picture.data.url">```and I get ```GET http://localhost:8100/user.facebook.cachedUserProfile.picture.data.url 404 (Not Found)```

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer That's not what the documentation suggests for usage.

Comment: @Daedalus got it, that's why I asked "...like a kind of ng-src for this...", can you tell me how to display the picture ?

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer [What in here are you having difficulty understanding](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.13/docs/api/ng/directive/ngSrc)?

Comment: @Daedalus got it now, ```<img ng-src="{{user.facebook.cachedUserProfile.picture.data.url}}">```thanks, I felt so stupid.